# GCP: Error Reporting: Deployment limit reached. Which are those deployments?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

Since recently GCP Error Reporting shows this error: "Deployment limit reached. You are only seeing data for the most recent deployments."

[image: GCP Error Reporting - Deployment Limit Reached]

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation which states which deployment this message talks about, how high the limit is or if there is a way to extend the limit.

Can anyone shed light on this? Maybe referencing hidden documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This deployment limit is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/quotas#deployment_limits). It actually mentions a *"10,000 deployment-error group pairs, where a deployment is a combination of service and version"*.

So this isn't about a specific service that reached a deployment limit but about the sum of all the service-version (App Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, ...) that you've ever deployed and enabled error reporting on.

This also means that the oldest service-version pairs are most likely not serving anymore.